# KeyNotFoundException Occur in wp7

Tags: windows-phone-7

[image]
I created WCF Web service for checking username,password and i use MYSQL database to check whether the username and password exists or not. i created application in WP7 with two textboxes for username,password and login button.When i run the application "KeyNotFoundException" will occur. Please tell me the reason.

`my code is here`

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Animation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
using Microsoft.Phone.Controls;
using consumeWCFwp7DB.ServiceReference1;
namespace consumeWCFwp7DB
{
public partial class MainPage : PhoneApplicationPage
{
    // Constructor
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void btnadd(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        ServiceReference1.ServiceClient obj = new ServiceReference1.ServiceClient();
        string username = txtusername.Text.ToString();
        string password = txtpassword.Text.ToString();
        obj.loginAsync(username, password);
   obj.loginCompleted+=new EventHandler<loginCompletedEventArgs>  (obj_loginCompleted);
    }
    void obj_loginCompleted(object sender, loginCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Error == null)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(e.ToString());
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Error");
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: On which line is the exception raised?

Comment: There is nothing is this code accessing a collection with a key, we are missing an important piece

Comment: Hello KooKiz I added the image with occurrence of exception

Comment: This exception will occur in Reference.cs file

Comment: If I Comsume the same web service in asp.net,It works fine.The exception will occur in wp7.Can any one help me pls...

Comment: What is the full call stack of the error?

Comment: As you haven't pasted the code where the exception occurs or the stack trace of the exception I am only guessing here, but it appears all of the other constructors of your `ServiceClient` are calling the `base` constructor. Is there something in the base class that needs to be initialized that the empty constructor does not handle properly?

Comment: Did you try updating the service reference?

Comment: The error may be occuring due to not properly setting the EndPointConfiguration i guess. Try again and when the error occurs again, click on the 'Copy exception detail to clipboard' link and get the exception details and provide here

Answer (score 0):

The exception is in Reference.cs, which means it is the WCF web service, not the phone application, which is throwing the error.
I would suggest that you debug your service while this runs, find out where the error is being thrown, and fix/catch it accordingly.

**EDIT:**
Just noticed your comment about it working fine from an ASP.NET app. That probably means that the key is not being received correctly. It also means that you are not handling errors.

Answer (score 0):

You should double check the binding settings for your service. I believe you only configured `WSHttpBinding` for it. But silverlight and windows phone 7 don't support `WSHttpBinding`. The only binding `Windows Phone 7` supports is `BasicHttpBinding`, so you should configure your service with `BasicHttpBinding`, then the client call would work.

The `KeyNotFoundException` is due to the default binding (`BasicHttpBinding`) not exist in the service's binding list (Only `WSHttpBinding` found in your service).

Answer (score 0):

Solution 
You modify file Web.config in your service :

```
<endpoint address="" 
          binding="basicHttpBinding" 
          contract="WcfServiceForWinMobile.IWin7MobileService"/>
```